# How to add defer to script tag in hiccup?

Tags: clojure, hiccup

I would like to add a [`defer`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) attribute to a script tab in [hiccup](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup/wiki/Syntax).

But things like `[:script {:src "main.js" :defer}]` return an error, and forms like `[:script {:src "main.js"} :defer]` insert "defer" in the middle of the script opening and closing tags.

Does anybody know how can i get something that translate to `<script src="main.js" defer></script>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a value for a `:defer` map key:

`[:script {:src "main.js" :defer true}]`

It should generate:

`<script src="main.js" defer="true"></script>`

which is equivalent to:

`<script src="main.js" defer></script>`

Comment: Thanks, I did not know these attributes can still be used as key/val!

Comment: It actually generates `<script src="main.js" defer=""></script>` which seems to be working as well.

Comment: Yes, you're right. More details: http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#sec-boolean-attributes